# How to correctly return a reference to temporary value?

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

For example, this function works as expect:

```rust
fn get_suffix(str: Option<&str>) -> u32 {
    str.and_then( |s| s.rsplit('_').next() )
       .and_then( |s| s.parse::<u32>().ok() )
       .unwrap_or(0)
}
```

But this gives me compile error:

```rust
fn get_suffix_from_path(path: &Path) -> u32 {
    path.file_stem()
        .and_then( |s| s.to_string_lossy().rsplit('_').next() )
        .and_then( |s| s.parse::<u32>().ok() )
        .unwrap_or(0)
}
```

```
328 |                     stem.to_string_lossy().rsplit('_').next())
    |                     ----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                     |
    |                     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
    |                     temporary value created here
```

I'm not entirely sure what it means. Is it caused by that fact `to_string_lossy()` creates `String` that would be dropped immediately when the closure ends? What's the idiomatic way to solve this?

I tried this:

```
stem.to_string_lossy().rsplit('_').next().and_then(|s| Some(s.to_owned()) )
```

It works, but it's not just ugly, but copies the string unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: the `Cow<str>` provided by `.to_string_lossy()` must exist until you parse its content and obtain an integer.

You just have to perform the parsing inside the closure where this `Cow<str>` exists.

```rust
use std::path::Path;

fn get_suffix_from_path(path: &Path) -> u32 {
    path.file_stem()
        .and_then(|s| {
            s.to_string_lossy()
                .rsplit('_')
                .next()
                .and_then(|s| s.parse().ok())
        })
        .unwrap_or(0)
}

fn main() {
    let p = Path::new("/tmp_56");
    let s = get_suffix_from_path(&p);
    println!("{:?} {:?}", p, s);
}
/*
"/tmp_56" 56
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, in your example the "extra" copy is actually necessary (you could stringify and *modify* the Cow that to_string_lossy returns, making it only one copy instead of potentially two).

You could also switch on if the cow is borrowed or owned, and return a cow that is either a sub-borrow or a modification of the owned string.  But that gets rather complicated.

In most cases, you could also choose to only support utf-8 paths, and use path.to_str(), and either just unwrapp it (causing a panic on non-utf8 paths) or handling it as an error in some other way.